# Difference between Story and Visual tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

What is the difference between the "story" and the "visual" tag? It seems to be the same.

Comment: Whenever you're in doubt, you can always check the [tag](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/story/info) [wikis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/visual/info)!

Answer (score 6):

[story](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story) is for a puzzle that has a story.

[visual](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual) is for a puzzle that relies on images.